# ng-Animate not working for a Hide and Show setting

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate, ng-show, ng-hide

I'm using AngularJS version 1.2.11. I've set a toolbar to slide in and out with a transition using ng-Animate (show and hide).

Here is the HTML:

```
 <div>
  <div class="full-height">
    <menu-main class="full-height pull-left"></menu-main>
    <menu-sub class="full-height pull-left" ng-show="data.active" ng-animate="'animate'">
    </menu-sub>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS for the same toolbar element

```
.animate.fade-hide, .animate..fade-show {
    -webkit-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 3.5s;
    -moz-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 3.5s;
    -o-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 3.5s;
    transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 3.5s;
}
.animate.fade-hide, {
    position: fixed;
    top: 500px;
    opacity: 0.3;
}
.animate.fade-hide, .animate.fade-hide-active 
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 500px;
    opacity: 0.3;
}
.animate.fade-show {
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
        opacity: 1;
}
.animate.fade-show, .animate.fade-show-active {
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
        opacity: 1;
}
```

The animation does not work, and I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The ng-animate attribute is deprecated in 1.2 and no longer used. Instead, animations are now class based.

Also make sure you are referencing `angular-animate.js` and adding ngAnimate as a dependent module:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate']);
```

You then name your animations, for example 'fadein' and 'fadeout', and decorate them with some additional classes following a special naming convention that can be found in the Angular [documentation](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.3/docs/guide/animations).

Another good source on the topic is [Year of moo](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html).

Fadein example:

```
/* After the transition this will be the only class remaining */
.fadein {
  -webkit-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 1.5s;
  -moz-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 1.5s;
  -o-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 1.5s;
  transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 1.5s;
  opacity: 1; /* Default value but added for clarity */
}

/* Initial state when showing */
.fadein.ng-hide-remove {
  opacity: 0;
  display: block !important;
}

/* Will transition towards this state */
.fadein.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

**Demo**: http://plnkr.co/edit/V9w2EwUh0unszf62TZZB?p=preview

Comment: There is a good article here: http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html

Comment: On my small project i can't see class transition when show/hide occur. I mean by class transition is the `.ng-hide-add` and `.ng-hide-remove`. I watch it on the official documentation it is appear for a while : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow . Do you have idea what is possible problem causing that?

Comment: @Dien Hard to tell without seeing the code. If you can replicate it in a plunker or mail me the code I can take a look (my e-mail is in my profile).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. Sorry that seem no problem with the `ngAnimate` i just found that it would not be animate inside ngMaterial dialog. Outside the dialog it will works as expected. Will try figure it my self first, may be i need you help later. Thanks :).